# Why isn't my todo list checkbox function applying to elements added with DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, queryselector

Working on creating a to-do list with JavaScript. I begin with a few default 'to-dos' that I coded into the html file. The structure of the list is like this

```
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Reminders To Do:</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;">Check off each task after completing it!</p>
<ul id="reminders" class="list-group">
    <div id="task">
         <li class="list-group-item" id="taskCheck"><input type="checkbox" name="task">Take out the trash</li>
    </div>
    <div id="task">
         <li class="list-group-item" id="taskCheck"><input type="checkbox" name="task">Email boss about project</li>
    </div>
    <div id="task">
        <li class="list-group-item" id="taskCheck"><input type="checkbox" name="task">Cancel subscriptions</li>
    </div>
    <div id="task">
        <li class="list-group-item" id="taskCheck"><input type="checkbox" name="task">Go to gym</li>
    </div>
 </ul>
```

I am able to add new events to this list by creating a form below with an eventListener on 'submit', etc. Everything there works as it should. The issue arises since I have a function in JS that should set the `"style: display: "none";"` hence removing the task from the list when completed. This works fine for the default events.

```
let eventForm = document.querySelector('#taskForm');
let eventName = document.querySelector('input[name="newTask"]');
let eventDate = document.querySelector('input[name="taskDate"');
let reminders = document.querySelector('#reminders');
let msg = document.querySelector('.msg');

eventForm.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);

function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(eventName.value === '' || eventDate.value === '') {
        msg.innerHTML = 'Please complete both fields.';

        setTimeout(() => msg.remove(), 3000);
    } else {
        let div = document.createElement('div');  //structure is ul -> div -> li -> input
        div.setAttribute('id', 'task');

        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.setAttribute('id', 'taskCheck');
        li.className += 'list-group-item'; //adds the bootstrap class to li
        li.innerHTML += '<input type="checkbox" name="task">'; //since input tag is nested within li element
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${eventName.value} | ${eventDate.value}`));

        div.appendChild(li); //adds li to a div within the list

        reminders.appendChild(div); //adds div into the list

        //resets form fields to empty for another task
        eventName.value = '';
        eventDate.value = '';

    }
}
```

Even though I see the new events added through my form, there is no response when I check/ uncheck the box.

My function for removing checked events is as such: *note I changed the functionality so instead of not showing the event, I'm testing with console.log();*

```
let reminderList = document.querySelectorAll('#reminders li');
let tasksCheck = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');


tasksCheck.forEach((task, i) => { //i holds the index of each task in the list

    task.addEventListener('change', () => {
        if(task.checked) {
            console.log('Task completed!');
        } else {
            console.log('Task not completed yet.');
        }
    })
})
```

I know the post is very long, would really appreciate help with this.

Comment: _"I am able to add new events to this list..."_ - do you mean new **todo items** to the list?  Also, it might be easier for the community to assist you on this if you could make a [mcve] in a [runnable stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), and included clear steps to reproduce, the expected behavior, and the actual behavior.  The description now is a bit difficult to follow-- a list of steps would be easier.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: It may become a good question, if images of new events update to the question.  looks like it is working partially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think the new tasks are not responding to the click event because you added the event listen before they were created. You can use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to solve this with code similar to the following:

```
let reminders = document.querySelector('#reminders'); // save the reminders
const handleTaskClick = e => {
if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {// check if it is a task element. You can use className here
  const taskInput = e.target;
  const task = taskInput.parentElement.parentElement; // get the task div
  const taskIndex = Array.from(reminders.children).indexOf(task); // convert to an array look for its index
  if(taskInput.checked) {
    console.log('Task completed!', taskIndex);
  } else {
    console.log('Task not completed yet.', taskIndex);
  }
 }
} 
// add the event listener to the reminders wrapper element #remiders
reminders.addEventListener('click', handleTaskClick);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that ended up being the issue!

Comment: Hey sorry to bother again... since my previous method looped with the reminders, I could simply access the index of the task that was checked. But here I have no index to find which task was checked? Do you have any suggestions to get around this?

Comment: No worries @timrockx I have added a way for you to retrieve the index of the task